# Cant login even i am typing manually while selenium listen browser

Tags: java, selenium, kotlin, web-scraping, browser-automation

im trying to web scrapping with selenium library in my java project. While i am try to login site with interactive behaviour (manually type username and password in login page) cant login. Site is under recaptcha protection, i think block login operation, because if i dont listen with browser with selenium, i can login.
Code;

```
                //Webdriver
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "data/src/main/kotlin/com/myapp/data/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
                WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup()

                //Chrome Options
                val options = ChromeOptions()

                // Fixing 255 Error crashes
                options.addArguments("--no-sandbox")
                options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

                // Options to trick bot detection -> i can trick bot detection with this code. Site ban me if dont use this lines
                options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
                options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"))
                options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false)
                options.addArguments("window-size=1920,1080")
                options.addArguments("disable-infobars")
                options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/tmp/afabc")

                // Changing the user agent
                val userAgent = UserAgent(RandomUserAgent().getRandomUserAgent())
                options.addArguments("user-agent=${userAgent}")


                //Chrome Driver
                val driver: WebDriver = ChromeDriver(options)
                driver.manage().window().position = Point(0,0)

                //Wait For Element
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofMillis(10000))
                val wait = WebDriverWait(driver,60)

                //Operation
                driver.get(LOGIN_SITE_URL)
```

```
val afterLoginPageSomeElementXpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/ul/li[1]/a"

 //For Listen user can login or not // İf i remove this code, i can login.
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(afterLoginPageSomeElementXpath)))
```

How can i bypass this issue? Anyone help?

Comment: Why people will help one who doesn't accept / upvote received answers and even not commenting if it helped etc?

Comment: what are u talking about? I am new learner, maybe you can explain me what i should do. I don't know even accept answers, only i upvote for good answers normally.

Comment: Really? You are more that 2 years here, asked a lot of questions and got answered where it was possible. When you are using absolutely FREE of charge service you should at least read the rules and say "Thanks" to people helped you. You have enough reputation to both accept and upvote given you answers.

Comment: @Prophet are u sure read rules? "Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". "

Comment: But i am learn that now, i must accept the correct answers, i will review my old answers.

Comment: I'm talking about accepting and upvoting given you answers, this is the way to say "Thanks" here and to indicate the question is resolved. I'm not talking about adding such comments.

Comment: okay, i am done it for my old answers. Thanks for notice.

Comment: I see. Well done! Keep doing that in the future as well.

Comment: The site's detecting you as a bot.  Which means they probably don't want you to use bots on it.  Be a good internet citizen and e-mail them to see if they have an API you can use.  Getting around that detection is a moving target, but there are some services you can use if you must... they will manually receive the captcha and get the token without using it... they then send it to your script so you can pass.   There are also free options to configure and/or re-write the webdriver to try to evade detection. Results will vary.